# asp.net cdn and scriptmanager

Tags: asp.net, cdn

I would like to understand cdn using.

**1** for jquery : i've read a lot of post in case of fallback for using local file

Generic solution :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/ZZjquery.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
        document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js' type='text/javascript' %3E%3C/script%3E"));
    }
</script>
```

And for jquery mobile

```
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/ZZjquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.css" />

<script type='text/javascript'>

    if (typeof $.mobile == 'undefined') {
        document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js'  %3E%3C/script%3E"));
        document.write(unescape("%3Clink rel='/stylesheet' href='/Content/JQ/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.css'  %3E%3C/script%3E"));
    }

</script>
```

i've also read a nicer solution :

```
 void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {

// map a simple name to a path

ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jQuery", new ScriptResourceDefinition {

    Path = "~/scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js",

    DebugPath = "~/scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js",

    CdnPath = "http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js",

    CdnDebugPath = "http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.3.2.js"

});

}
```

**But in this case how can i load css file from local?**

**2** Another asking is what about MicrosoftAjax and other stuff ?

i use scriptmanger like that :

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnableCdn="true"  />
```

And i not include all WebForms and MicrosoftAjax scripts in my BundleCollection

But what happend if Microsoft Ajax CDN Fall ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Ok i've solved my problems with

**1**

in App_start

```
 Dim srd As New ScriptResourceDefinition()
            srd.Path = "~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            srd.DebugPath = "~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            srd.CdnPath = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"
            srd.LoadSuccessExpression = "window.jQuery"

            ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("JQ", srd)

...
```

then in my masterpage

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnableCdn="true"  >
        <Scripts>


            <asp:ScriptReference Name="JQ" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/InitMobile.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="JQM" />
             <asp:ScriptReference Name="JQT" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MyJQ" />
        </Scripts>

    </asp:ScriptManager>

       <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ScriptContent" />
```

My ScriptContent is used in my pages for init some jquery stuff

For the css file i test if one of his class exist by this code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
    <script type='text/javascript'>

        try{
            var hasstyle = false;
            var fullstylesheets = document.styleSheets;
            for (var sx = 0; sx < fullstylesheets.length; sx++) {
                var sheetclasses = fullstylesheets[sx].rules || document.styleSheets[sx].cssRules;
                for (var cx = 0; cx < sheetclasses.length; cx++) {
                    if (sheetclasses[cx].selectorText == ".ui-btn") {
                        hasstyle = true; break;
                        //return classes[x].style;              
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (err) { }

            if (!hasstyle) {
                document.write('<link href="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Content/JQ/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" />');
            }

    </script>
```

**2**

Scriptmanager work alone....

eg. this output

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.5/6/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
(window.Sys && Sys.WebForms)||document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js"><\/script>');//]]>
</script>
```